# FFmpeg Audio Video Synchronisation

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-camera

I have been trying to create a video using the video feed from the Android Camera...

The preview frames from the camera are captured and are piped to `ffmpeg` input and audio is captured using `AudioRecord` (sample rate: 44100, channel: mono) and is feed to `ffmpeg` using the same technique...
The video is generated successfully as expected...But the audio and video appear to be out of sync...

The audio initially appears to be lagging from video, at some point it equals the video and then leads from the video as it progresses which clearly states that the playback speed of the audio stream is faster as compared to that of the video...

The command used is as follows :

```
ffmpeg -f image2pipe -vcodec mjpeg -i - -i audioPipe -b:v 1024k -f flv -vcodec libx264 -minrate 512k -maxrate 1024k -bufsize 8092k -acodec copy -preset ultrafast -g:v 3 -acodec copy out.flv
```

I've even tried the same with `-async 1` but ended with the same result as above...

Is there any way to mux the two streams in perfect synchrony...?

Thanks...

Comment: you could start here : http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial05.html

Comment: Have already been through the same, but the technique is skewed more towards the FFmpeg API rather than the CLI, which I am looking into...